# Why is a slap shot in ice hockey more powerful than a wrist shot?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

I am trying to apply my school physics knowledge to understand why a [wrist shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrist_shot) in ice hockey is less powerful than a [slap shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapshot).

In my understanding the formula that governs the physics is

$$m * dV = F * dT$$

where $m$ is the mass of the puck, $dT$ is the amount of time during which the force is applied to the puck

- with the slap shot `dT` is almost instantaneous, the puck is in contact with the stick only at the moment of contact

  > ~ and further more via follow-through, as it was pointed out
- with the wrist shot `dT` is considerably longer, the puck is in contact with the stick all the way through

So given that `F` and `m` are the same, the momentum of  the wrist shot should be greater, or shouldn't it?

**UPDATE**: So I realize now that my questions is somewhat ill-posed, because my original assumption was that with the slap shot the amount of time to transfer the momentum would be near to instantaneous, but I didn't account for the follow-through.

Comment: It's considered more powerful because its *measured* velocity is higher, not because of some abstract whiteboard model. Physics is not mathematics.

Comment: @JohnDoty i am not arguing, please explain

Comment: There is more to it than meets the eye. In a slap shot, the stick bends, storing potential energy. As it straightens, it flings the puck. [SLAPSHOT Physics in Slow Motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsCdywftyok)

Comment: @mmesser314 the stick is supposed to be bent in wrist shot too

Answer (score 2):

In fact it’s mostly the other way around.  $dT$ is the time the puck is in contact with the blade of the stick and it’s roughly the same (to a factor of 2 depending on the players) for both shots.

In a slap-shot the blade of stick hits the puck with a much greater velocity and the follow-through allows for additional contact between the blade and the puck, transferring additional momentum and compensating in part for the swiftness of the motion.  There is also a bending effect due to the stick. Finally, “the slapshot requires work from the player’s legs, torso, arms, and shoulders, hence the significant amount of energy delivered to the puck.”[2]. The rotational speed of the player as he or she hits the puck is also an important factor [2].

In a wrist shot, the blade has a more limited follow through and basically does not transfer much momentum except from the restricted rotational motion of the wrist, which delivers nowhere near the energy of all the muscle groups involved in a slap shot. There is no bending effect.

Note that curved blades increase the contact area between the cylindrical puck and the blade, typically resulting in harder shots that are also somewhat easier to direct (at least in theory; during a game the action is so fast that players rarely have time to properly aim their wrist shots).

Slap shots take longer to deliver and require more space because of the swing back and follow through.  Good goalies have more time to prepare and also can get some sense of the direction of the short from the follow through but the short is usually faster than a wrist shot and thus not necessarily easier to handle.

Slap shots are preferred by players near the blue line because they do have more space and the harder short may deflect on players or sticks just ahead of goalie without loosing too much velocity.  Wrist shots are preferred closer to the goalie for quickness of execution.

For more quantitative discussions:

> 1. Cross, Rod, and Crawford Lindsey. "The slap shot in ice hockey." The Physics Teacher 56, no. 1 (2018): 7-9.
> 2. Haché, Alain. "A cool sport full of physics." The Physics Teacher 46.7 (2008): 398-402

Comment: yes, the instantaneous velocity of the slap shot is higher but that would be it, it's the follow-through that i missed that accounts for additional momentum transfer, i guess that explains it in a nut shell, i wish i could see the formulas that solidify it, thank you for the answer

Comment: @TridentD'Gao I just added two references which discuss the flexibility of the stick as an additional effect present only in the slap shot.

Comment: but the tension of the bent stick can and should be applied to a wrist shot too, couldn't it?

Comment: there is no way a wrist shot can bend the stick to the extent a slap shot can.  The interesting part is that the contact time with the slap shot should be so long…

Comment: and by saying it you mean that if a player delivers a significant part of their weight on a stick making it bent under this weight it would be no par to the tension of stick of the slap shot?

Answer (score 1):

Force is not the same. Nor is it constant through either stroke. Consequently we can't apply any high school physics approaches that rely on constant forces. If we had a very good way of measuring the acceleration of the puck (perhaps an ultra high speed camera) and a bit of calculus, we could curve-fit our data and calculate the area under the curve to apply $\int_0^{t'} F dt = \int_0^{t'} ma dt = m \Delta v$. Alternately, we could take some measurements of the stick and the athlete and model them as systems of springs, although I suspect that while the stick might be simple enough for such an approach, the athlete is too complicated for such a model to work.

I suspect that the force curves would look something like this, as the stick flexes on impact, the athlete follows through the stroke, and the stick unflexes as the athlete's follow-through is unable to maintain the acceleration required to keep the force high and the stick flexed.

[image]

We can apply some high school physics to estimate the exit velocity of the puck, given some measurements about the player's stroke. To do this, we treat the whole slap shot interaction between the player+stick and the puck as a **collision**, with the time the puck spent in contact with the stick bundled into a black box where mystery physics happened.

In the slap shot, a big object with some velocity hits a small object with some other velocity. At the moment of impact, the athlete did his best to use his muscles to keep the stick from changing its tip velocity on impact, so we can approximate the tip of the stick as having the whole mass of the stick and the athlete. This is much larger than the mass of the puck, so if this was a perfectly elastic collision, and the stick had its maximum velocity at the point of impact, the puck would leave the athlete immediately traveling at almost twice the initial relative velocity of the tip of the stick with respect to the puck. We know that the collision is not perfectly elastic, and the player is not infinitely massive, so the exit velocity of the puck will be somewhere between 1 and 2 times the maximum velocity of the stick - probably closer to 2 than to 1.

For the wrist shot, since we start with the stick and puck in contact, we have a shove: all work done on the objects in contact is done on both objects at once as a gestalt, which then separates into parts if part of the gestalt (the tip of the stick) slows down and part (the puck) remains at the maximum velocity. So the exit velocity of the puck is exactly the maximum velocity of the tip of the stick.

so, if we...

let $v_s$ be the maximum velocity of the stick in the slap shot

let $v_w$ be the maximum velocity of the stick in the wrist shot

let $V_s$ be the exit velocity of the puck in the slap shot

let $V_w$ be the exit velocity of the puck in the wrist shot

then...

$v_s \lt V_s \lt 2 v_s$

$v_w = V_w$

I would guess that $v_w \lt v_s$, in which case it would be certain that $V_w \lt V_s$, likely by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: please leave a comment on how you made these graphs, if i had a tool that showed to me the answer like this, i would not probably asked the question in a first place

Comment: @TridentD'Gao The graphs are strictly guesses. They are not plots of any function; I drew them manually.

Comment: maybe a few words on how you made them?